# PHP: where should I put my includes?

Tags: php, performance, include, jit

I have coded a set of basic functions I'm using in various scripts, but very seldom more than once in the same script.

Since I was schooled only in compiled languages programming I may not fully understand the dynamics of interpreted / JIT compiled languages: When using apache's PHP module, is each instruction compiled and then executed (like it happens in the CLI, for example), or is the whole script JIT compiled and then executed?

In case it's per instruction compiling/executing, should I have a block of `require_once` at the beginning of the file (which seems way more sane to me) or would it be more efficient to include them only if I need them (inside `if` blocks and so...)?

Comment: You can include anywhere. But its better if you get accustomed with some OOP MVC frameworks.

Comment: I'm working my way up to that. I've coded a lot of Java and C++ and plan to go full OOP in PHP, but I guess inside of me there's still an ANSI C guy... The question is (since there's an index page script involved among others): which option is more efficient? Or even better: is there any difference?

Comment: It just depends. Purpose of compiled and interpreted languages are way different. Most of the cases the includes are best done when they are actually needed. Depends on the flow of execution as well.

Comment: In the long run, its best to just avoid include non-sense and use a well-written auto loader that can always find your class...  Stuff that you use everywhere, you can pre-include so the autoloader doesn't get triggered for it...

Comment: autoload, that's a cool thing I didn't know about :)

Comment: @Stephen has a point here- autoload is a pretty good way to go. I'd argue that I've never seen efficiency take a hit by including too many files. It's the inclusing of too much LOGIC that makes performance take a hit. Separation into classes and including a bunch of files that way has never slowed my stuff down, but then again I haven't used PHP for something extremely large scale (medium scale at best). I've been on other systems with Java and CS backends on large scale projects instead so it's hard for me to comment on that side of it.

Comment: Anytime I've tried to "improve" autoload by caching locations or whatever, i've never beaten the FS just doing a couple of fstats..  The website I work on does 500k hits on PHP recently and almost no load with a 100% autoloaded setup.  We use the rails convention where class name SomethingBlarg  is in something_blarg.php and have a few paths for organization (models, controllers, managers)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event that those included scripts are procedural, they are included inline, meaning that any variable definitions, executable code, etc are evaluated when the include happens. Of course, if it's a class, then you have access to that class from there on out. Some people opt to, in certain situations, use switches or if statements to decide whether or not to include a file that contains logic to be executed. It can be handy, or sloppy, depending on how it's used.

If you're worried about memory usage because of includes, then using them in if blocks isn't a terrible thing, in my book, but that should be a very deliberate choice because you'll get a bunch of hard core OO guys getting on your case immediately over it shouting that it's bad design.

I try to put all my includes at the top of a file unless it is a file that is completely superfluous and specific to a single usage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Would you include template files at top as well?

Comment: Personally, yeah. I'm a huge stickler on organization, and it's been rewarding to me in the past. Would you opt to include them elsewhere? If so, what are your reasons for that?

Comment: For templates including just in place makes it simpler in most cases. @quinxorin explained it quite well.

Comment: I think it CAN make it simpler but it's maybe better to get in the habit of not just including all over the place "just because it makes it simpler". 
"Simpler" and "Easier to edit 2 weeks down the road" are two very different scenarios a lot of the time  :P

Comment: If you could enlighten us with such models.. cuz its the topic's context.

Comment: I think that topic is quite broad and out of the scope of this context, actually. At that point we get into application design and talking about when to allow exceptions to your design rules and when not to. If it increases efficiency I'd say do it- but typically only in the case that it doesn't make modification more difficult down the road. There are literally an infinite number of cases where this decision has to be made so it's hard to shed light on something so braod.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike compiled languages, what you're suggesting is possible; you may put `include` statements in an `if()` block, and it will only run them if the block runs. And yes, you will realize a performance increase from this method.

In PHP, `include` (and the other inclusion operators) behave very logically: as if the code from the included file had been copied and pasted right there. It is also possible to define a function at any place in a file, even after the function is called; therefore, in PHP you can improve readability by putting your `include` statements at the bottom of the file, rather than the top.

Comment: I like the way you put this, though I would argue that readability is honestly quite similar between a pile of includes up top or a pile of includes down below, particularly in that it is not very common to include stuff at the bottom, is it? (I ask in all seriousness)